# How can I programmatically change the view controller displayed by a tab bar item?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an iOS app with a tab bar controller that was created using the storyboard. One of the tab bar buttons segues to a table view controller (via a navigation controller) which displays a list of user-selected 'favourite' items. However if that list of items is empty I want to display a different view controller with a simple static message. Is it possible to programmatically change the 'target' view controller of a tab bar button/segue? If so, how? Or is there a better alternative to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: why doesn't use UIView and add view in superView of tableview if table count zero

Answer (score 1):

Don't deal this with the tabBar index's.

Better For your scenario, Try this :

In the `ViewDidLoad` , check for the `favourite items`.

```
 if(empty ){
   //hide the tableView(tableView =nil ) && Show the Static Message.
}else{
   // Hide the static Message && initiate the tableView
}
```

Comment: This looks likely! I tried something similar but I didn't hide the default tableView so it didn't work correctly. Will give this a go and report back.

Comment: Instead of using a UITableViewController, use a custom UIViewController that has an 'empty view' and a `UITableView`. Ideally use a method that can be invoked to update the UI from within the `viewDidLoad` that you also call when the first favorite is added.

Comment: In the end I created an automatic segue to the 'show if empty' ViewController in the ViewDidLoad method of the favourites list TableViewController, if the favourites list was empty. Seemed like the simplest option to save re-building the listing part.

Answer (score -1):

Its too simple

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:i];
```

**i** - Index of your tab number that you want to redirect.